# Android: How to programmatically read SMS details and filter it? Is there any restriction like iOS?

Tags: android, sms

I need Read SMS Details, get SMS sender's phone number, remove read messages, sometimes broadcast SMS to all senders. It's like a Register Server. I heard it is possible to do those things. But, how to do that? Any suggestion?

Moreover, is there any restriction like iOS? e.g. iOS does not allow you send SMS at background, you have to ask user's permission. You can't access SMS database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! No body answer me. After few days research. I got several great examples on GitHub. The best one is  nyaruka / android-sms-relay .
[SMS Relay on GitHub](https://github.com/nyaruka/android-sms-relay)

> **Android SMS Relay**
> e
> This is a simple SMS relayer. It essentially turns your Android phone into an SMS modem that will relay messages to an HTTP server of your choice and vice versa.
>
> We use this quite a bit in our work, so we thought we'd open it up to the world. Note that this particular codebase is still pretty Alpha and we've been cleaning it up for the outside world. It very well might break, but we appreciate any and all testing and bug reports.
>
> Things that make it different than other solutions:
>
> we are backed by a database for persistence, we think that makes it less likely a message will be dropped in the case of power outages, reboots, or other issues
> we have a prettier message UI than the other guys
> we will toggle Wifi on or off in the case of network errors.. this can be useful in places where WiFi is not reliable as the phone will then back down to GSM when it is acting up (and automatically switch back to WiFi when it starts working again)
> easy integration with our RapidSMS httprouter module. (http://github.com/nyaruka/rapidsms-httprouter)
> This is still pretty early stuff, so any feedback or bug reports much appreciated.